# Are all matrices of order $n^2$ bijective linear transformations?

Tags: linear-algebra

My linear algebra book says that all matrices $T\in L(V,V)$ (of order $n^2$ if the dimension of $V$ is $n$) are linear transformations. Also, each such mapping is bijective.

Shouldn't only invertible matrices be such bijective linear transformations?

EDIT: I may have been confused. Is it the bijection between $T(V,V)$ and $F[n^2]$ that the book mayhave been talking about?

Thanks

Comment: Your edit is probably what the book is talking about. If you fix a basis of $V$, then each linear operator on $V$ has a unique matrix representation.

Answer (score 0):

Only invertible matrices give bijective linear transformation because
for finite-dimensional vector spaces, rank-nullity theorem yields that
T is one-one if and only if T is onto.
Now, AX=0 gives X=0 whenever A is injective.